# Sed to search regex pattern and remove line with above pattern

Tags: linux, sed, pattern-matching, text-processing

this is my file.txt content. Here I'm trying to search pattern `text: 'About'` and remove `items:[{` line with the command as below:

file.txt:

```
                items: [{
                        text: 'About',
                        handler: function() { TP.aboutWindow() }
```

Command:
`sed -n -i -E '/text\: \'About\'/{n; $p; x; d}; x; 1!p; ${x;p;}' file.txt`

but it seems to be not working. Is there any way to make it work to remove line above pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i "N;/\n.*text: 'About'/"'!P;D' file.txt
```

*Details*:

- `-i` - file inplace replacement mode on
- `N` - opens a two-line window throughout the whole file (it reads the next line prepended with a newline into pattern space)
- `\n.*text: 'About'` matches a newline, then any text and then `text: 'About'`
- `!P;D` - if there is a match, do not print the first line, then delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: Perhaps one set of quotes is enough i.e. `sed -i 'N;/\n.*text: '\''About'\''/!P;D' file` (I expect you suffered problems using double quotes with regards to the `!` which the shell wanted to interpolate). N.B. the idiom `'\''` closes off the existing quote, quotes a single quote in the shell beneath and the final quote opens the next quoted text.

Comment: @potong Well, I did not have any issues, this is just how I prefer to concatenate strings (`"N;/\n.*text: 'About'/"` + `'!P;D'`)

Comment: Curious, why double quotes for one string and single for the next?

Answer (score 3):

In case you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following with `awk` + `tac` combination here. This will print the output on terminal, once you are happy with results you can append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` at last of following command too.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk '
found && /items:/{
  found=""
  next
}
/text: \047About\047/{
  found=1
}
1' | 
tac
```